# How to get a list of files into a Powershell array

Tags: powershell

I want to get a list of files into a Powershell variable that I can use in subsequent code.

Files:
file1.csv
file2.csv

```
   $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem .\file*.csv
```

But the output that I get is:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                       
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                       
-a----         4/10/2022   1:52 AM             31 file1.csv                                                                  
-a----         4/10/2022   1:52 AM             31 file2.csv
```

I am trying to get the output `$sourceFiles = "file1.csv","file2.csv"`

How is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you want to get an array of file names you can wrap the expression in parentheses and call the `Name` property: `$sourceFiles = (Get-ChildItem .\file*.csv).Name`

Comment: generally speaking you WANT to keep the objects with all the available properties so that you can use them later in your code. if you are SURE that you will never want to use any of the added info,  then grab only what you want. the `-Name` parameter switch will give JUST the name of the file. [or the relative path & the name] if you want the full path,  then grab the value in the `.FullName` property.

Answer (score 5):

You should add -Name to the Get-ChildItem command.

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem .\file*.csv -Name
Write-Host $sourceFiles
```

According with [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) -Name does the job.

> Gets only the names of the items in the location. The output is a string object that can be sent down the pipeline to other commands. Wildcards are permitted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in need of this these days, and I ended up writing a PowerShell script:

```
$InputFolder = $args[0]
$OutputFile = $args[1]
$BinStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($OutputFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
$BinWriter = [System.IO.BinaryWriter]::new($BinStream)
$InputFolder
    | Get-ChildItem
    | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime
    | ForEach-Object {
        $Data = $_ | Get-Content -AsByteStream -Raw
        $BinWriter.Write($Data)
        }
$BinWriter.Close()
```

You can sort by a different object property, maybe datetime of creation, LastWriteTime just happens to be the one that I needed. The reason I cannot sort by name is that my file names do not have the index suffix padded with zeros.

There's probably a more straight-forward way, without diving into .NET classes, but I don't have much of a PowerShell skill, so whatever I put together to satisfy my immediate need is a result of quick googling and browsing through PowerShell reference online.